# RegEx performance in Objective-C vs Python

Tags: python, objective-c, regex

This question might seem vague, sorry. Does anybody have experience writing RegEx with Objective-C and Python? I am wondering about the performance of one vs the other? Which is faster in terms of 1. runtime speed, and 2. memory consumption? I have a Mac OS application that is always running in the background, and I'd like my app to index some text files that are being saved, and then save the result... I could write a regex method in my app in Obj-C, or I could potentially write a separate app using Perl or Python (just a beginner in Python).

(Thanks, I got some good info from some of you already. Boo to those who downvoted; I am here to learn, and I might have some stupid questions time to time - part of the deal.)

Comment: "Which is best?" for what?  Best for using Apple license?  Best use of memory?  Please provide some measurable thing you're trying to optimize.  Then we can tell you how to measure it.

Comment: Why are you comparing the regex engines of two entirely different languages? This is like asking "Which moon has a shorter orbit, Titan or Proteus?"

Comment: In my Mac OS application I will be doing some text processing, and I was wondering if doing that in Python would be faster.

Comment: @janeh If all you’re looking for is fast regexes, then neither of those languages is going to be a very good choice.  Perl’s regexes are written in very tightly coded C, and are known to be the fastest and most flexible regexes available. The only exception is with pathological patterns that degenerate in any recursive backtracker, whether Perl’s, Java’s, or Python’s. Those can be addressed by using the highly recommended `RE2` library as a replacement plugin.

Comment: @tchrist: Is anyone working on porting that good re code to python? Then we can do away with the spitting perl llama :P

Comment: @bukzor Last time I did an analysis of what Python’s regex were missing compared with Perl’s, I came up with 36 (**thirty-six**) different regex features that Python lacked. You aren’t going to amend that deficiency anytime real soon now. If all you want is decent Unicode support, though, you can use Matthew Barnett’s `regex` library instead.

Comment: If your text processing is simple enough to write without reflex in c, then you can get a lot of performance. There are also OS x calls to convert strings into words, etc.

Comment: @tchrist: i was imagining a direct port of the perl regex machinery into python. Hypothetically, that would fix your 36 problems at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re looking for raw speed, neither of those two would be a very good choice.   For execution speed, you’d choose Perl. For how quickly you could code it up, either Python or Perl alike would easily beat the time to write it in Objective C, just as both would easily beat a Java solution.  High-level languages that take less time to code up are always a win if all you’re measuring is time-to-solution compared with solutions that take many more lines of code.

As far as actual run-time performance goes, Perl’s regexes are written in very tightly coded C, and are known to be the fastest and most flexible regexes available. The regex optimizer does a lot of very clever things to the compiled regex program, such as applying an Aho–Corasick start-point optimization for finding the start of an alternation trie, running in O(1) time.  Nobody else does that. Heck, I don’t think anybody else but Perl even bothers to optimize alternations into tries, which is the thing that takes you from O(n) to O(1), because the compiler spent more time doing something smart so that the interpreter runs much faster. Perl regexes also offer substantial improvements in debugging and profiling. They’re also more flexible than Python’s, but the debugging alone is enough to tip the balance.

The only exception on performance matters is with certain pathological patterns that degenerate when run under any recursive backtracker, whether Perl’s, Java’s, or Python’s. Those can be addressed by using the highly recommended `RE2` library, written by Russ Cox, as a replacement plugin. I *know* it’s available as a transparent replacement regex engine for Perl, and I’m pretty sure I remember seeing that it was also available for Python, too.

On the other hand, if you really want to use Python but just want a more expressive and robust regex library, particularly **one that is well-behaved on Unicode,** then you want to use Matthew Barnett’s `regex` module, available for both Python2 and Python3.  Besides conforming to tr18’s level-1 compliance requirements (that’s the standards doc on Unicode regexes), it also has all kinds of other clever features, some of which are completely *sui generis*.  If you’re a regex connoisseur, it’s very much worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

> In my Mac OS application I will be doing some text processing, and I was wondering if doing that in Python would be faster.

It will be faster in terms of development time, almost certainly. For nearly all software projects, development time dominates runtime as a measure of success.

If you mean runtime, then you're almost certainly doing premature optimization, unless you've shown that slow code will cause unbearable/noticeable user-interface slowdown.

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.
>   -- [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: "For nearly all software projects, development time dominates runtime as a measure of success." - I don't fit in that group; I did mean runtime speed... The faster it finishes, the faster the memory will be released for other processes.

Comment: @janeh: Please actually **update** the question to actually state what your actual requirements are.